# Range for syntax

Tags: c++, c++11

When I write something like this:

```
int data[] = {10,44,56,78,8};      
int i = 0;
for(int element : data)
   ...
```

that `for` is then translated by the compiler in a regular `for`? is that `for`
only a syntactic sugar?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer on your question? is your compiler rejecting that syntax? If so, which compiler are you using? If GCC, are you using the `-std=c++0x` flag to enable C++11 features?

Comment: Yes I can. No, my compiler isn't rejecting  that syntax. I only want to know if that for is by the compiler translated in a regular for.

Comment: If it is translated into the traditional syntax, so what? You never see the translation, and the code will execute the same regardless of how the compiler internally represents the structure of the commands. What difference does it make whether the compiler represents the new `for` statement as a transformation to the traditional format or as an entirely separate kind of statement?

Comment: @Kennedy, could it be an optimization issue?

Comment: @RobKennedy, it makes a difference because in C++ an "obvious" expression such as `b != e` could be overloaded to have surprising side-effects. It is (occasionally) important to know _exactly_ what a range-based `for` loop expands to, and indeed the standard specifies _exactly_ what it translates to. It is just syntactic sugar (albeit powerful sugar) for something that could already be expressed in standard C++ (sftrabbit's answer shows the specifics.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard defines the range-based `for` statement to be equivalent to:

```
{
  auto && __range = range-init;
  for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
             __end = end-expr;
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin ) {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

In your case, `range-init` is `(data)`, `begin-expr` is `__range`, `end-expr` is `__range + 5`, `for-range-declaration` is `int element` and `statement` is `...`. That is, if we substitute all of these, your `for` loop is equivalent to:

```
{
  auto && __range = (data);
  for ( auto __begin = __range,
             __end = __range + 5;
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin ) {
    int element = *__begin;
    ...
  }
}
```

Whether this translation is actually done by the compiler is an implementation detail. The only thing you can guarantee is that your code will be equivalent to the above code.

Comment: By the way, is `auto a, b` equivalent to `auto a; auto b` or `(guessed type) a, b` ?

Comment: Good question. Each variable declared will have its type deduced, so it's equivalent to `auto a; auto b;`. The entire *decl-specifier_seq* is carried over, so for `const auto a, b;` it would be equivalent to `const auto a; const auto b;`.

Comment: Ok, so for me is there no way to check if that translation is done? i.e. for Java if I write an enhanced for and then I decompile the .class I can see that the compiler did that translation...

Comment: You could look at the generated assembly, but unless you compile without optimizations, chances are it will look almost but not quite, entirely unlike the original.

Comment: In `auto a, b = ...` both types must have the same type. It is not equivalent to `auto a; auto b;` because that's not valid (there's nothing to infer the type from)

Comment: @JonathanWakely I was (perhaps wrongly) assuming that they had just omitted the initialisers. I believe that `auto a, b = ...;` would not compile because `a` doesn't have an initialiser, no?

Comment: Oops, good point, _that's_ not valid either! I think I should give up now ;)  I meant in `auto a=..., b=...;` both _variables_ must have the same type. There's only one type inferred , not one for each variable, so the initializers must have the same type and it's not the same as `auto a=...; auto b=...;`