# In for (int val :arr), what does the colon mean?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

void Show()
{
    for (int val : arr) {
        cout << val;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Show();
    return 0;
}
```

result will be 123 . 
 i will be very grateful to get explanation of this  -int val :arr- 
 specifically what - : -  does here ?  what is it .

Comment: `for (int val :arr){` This simply iterates `arr`. It's called range for loop.

Comment: It's a range-based for loop. It's not part of C, by the way.

Comment: Checkout documentation of range-for at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14379741/335858)

Comment: @dasblibkenlight Isn't that an exact duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

It is called [range loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
for (int val : arr)
   cout << val;
```

works the same as:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
for (int i=0;i<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);i++)
{
   int val=arr[i];
   cout << val;
}
```

But range loop can do far more.

It simply means loop through all members. Keep in mind some classes can have a complicated iterator and a `range for` runs through an array in a clean way. Also, notice it is a `c++11` feature.

Comment: The pedantic equivalent code is not that.

Comment: @Jarod42, I mitigated the language. Are you talking about this case or general range for?

Comment: Current wording is better. And I talk of general case.

Comment: Must you use the brittle `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)` technique? It's probably the worst thing one can teach to a C++ novice. Especially when there are far superior techniques.

Comment: @StoryTeller, what technique to use without changing the definition of `arr`?

Comment: `template<typename T, std::size_t N> constexper std::size_t array_size(T(&)[N]) { return N; }`. Unlike the sizeof trick, `array_size(arr)` won't compile for a pointer, only an array.

Comment: @StoryTeller, you are right. However, this code equivalence is just for this example and not for a pointer. For a different type it can be very complicated and in no way similar to what I have posted. I admit that.